# difference in placeholder size in input in chrome and firefox browser

Tags: html, css

I have set background image to input tag, and height of background is mismatched in firefox and chrome. I need chrome like behaviour.
After researching i found that :placeholder-shown height is same as ::placeholder height in firefox.

```
input::placeholder { 
    background-image: url('../../../../public/images/icons/calender1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

[image: in chrome view]

this is chrome view

[image: in firefox view]

this is view in firefox

Comment: Just set `background-size: 1em;` - adjust the number as needed. But just a side note, but that is a *lot* of `../` in your path; you may be better off using a URL like `/public/images/...` so that if your file structure ever changes, you're not stuck fixing a bunch of relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
input{
  background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg',     sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='image.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```